# Bayesian informative hypotheses testing

Tags: r, bayesian, hypothesis-test

I work on a Bayesian project, and I have a question regarding Bayesian informative hypothesis testing in r. I use the 'bain' package to see what hypothesis is favored. I did a multiple linear regression:

```
data(trees) # R's trees data
head(trees)

summary(model0 <- lm(Volume ~ Girth + Height, data = trees))
```

I want to test the hypothesis that the influence of Girth is bigger than the influence of Height in the following manner: b1 > b2 + 0.2 sd (where b1 is the regression coefficient of Girth and b2 is the regression coefficient of Height). I tried specifying it in the following way, but it does not recognize the specification of the standard deviation/error:

```
out <- summary(model0)
sd_height <- out$coefficients[3,2]

results <- bain(model0, hypothesis = 'Girth > 0; Height > 0;Girth > Height + 0.2*sd_height', fraction = 1, standardize = F)
```

If I specify it like this, I get the following warning:

Some of the parameters referred to in the 'hypothesis' do not correspond to parameter names of object 'x'.
The following parameter names in the 'hypothesis' did not match any parameters in 'x': sd_height
The parameters in object 'x' are named: (Intercept), Girth, Height

Does anyone know how I can specify that standard deviation/error in the bain function in order to test my hypothesis? Thanks!